# Unsigned long long int as an array index in C on a very big array

Tags: c

I need a very big array to represent a series of points. To be more exact I need 256 * UINT_MAX points that have x and y values between 0 and 1. What I've tried so far is this but when I try to access array[i] my program crashes. What I can use to iterate through that array and to allocate that memory? Thank you!

```
unsigned long long int N = (unsigned long long int) 256 * (unsigned long long int) UINT_MAX;
float** array = (float**) malloc( N * sizeof(float*));
    
for(unsigned long long int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
      array[i] = (float*)malloc(2 * sizeof(float));
      printf("Allocated");
      array[i][0] = (float) rand() / RAND_MAX;
      array[i][1] = (float) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        
}
```

Comment: You are allocating an array of pointers, each pointer pointing to a heap-allocated array of two floats. This is an *terribly bad* idea. Don't do that. Even If your machine can allocate an 8 terabyte array, which it probably cannot, allocating a **trillion** 8-byte arrays is on a different level altogether.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why do you need so much space? If you _really_ need that much, you're going to need to re-architect your approach to accessing it... perhaps with a database? File on disk using `mmap` at least?

Comment: You should also be aware that the pseudo-random sequence from `rand` is going to repeat itself many times.

Answer (score 2):

Your programs crashes because you try to allocate a **HUGE** amount of memory you likely do not have (without checking the result of `malloc` is `NULL`). Indeed, `UINT_MAX` is close to 4e9 on many mainstream system and so you try to allocate at least `8 * 256 * 4e9 = 8` TB of memory (without taking into account allocation in the loop that will be insanely slow)!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on a 64-bit platform, then it's likely that

```
        UINT_MAX == 4294967295
sizeof (float *) == 8
```

so you are trying to allocate *8 **terabytes*** of memory in one chunk, which is almost certainly failing.  Check the return value of `malloc` to make sure it isn't `NULL`.

Why do you think you need to allocate that large an array?  What kind of data are you trying to model?

Comment: My professor asked me to do this. To run the program with different number of threads to see the speedup. Tbh he didn't said exactly if we need to store the array of gust generate random number and count how many points respect a condition. But I guess I don't need to store all of them